# Errors on generated code from Typegen

Tags: polkadot-js, typescript

We are following the polkadot{.js} [docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/typegen/) on TypeScript user generated for Chain modules. We are trying to get our custom chain module types into Typescript. We can generate fine however the generated files wont compile. They have hundreds of errors. like:

```
Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDispatchError'.
```

and

```
 Cannot find name 'SpWeightsWeightV2Weight'.
```

has anyone done this. the docs seam like they are out of date and the example is over a year old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

I was importing the default type augmentations with `import '@polkadot/api-augment'`

Removed that and it works fine. Types show up in TS.